# Docusign: Is Embedding using JS secure?

Tags: digital-signature, docusignapi

Lets say I have a base url.

Now a userA uploads a document and userB has to sign it.

using this code:

```
// To run this sample
//  1. Copy the file to your local machine and give .js extension (i.e. example.js)
//  2. Change "***" to appropriate values
//  3. Install async and request packages
//     npm install async
//     npm install request
//  4. execute
//     node example.js 
//

var     async = require("async"),       // async module
        request = require("request"),       // request module
        fs = require("fs");         // fs module

var     email = "***",              // your account email
        password = "***",           // your account password
        integratorKey = "***",      // your Integrator Key (found on the Preferences -> API page)
        recipientName = "***",      // recipient (signer) name
        recipientEmail = "***",     // recipient email address  
        documentName = "***",       // copy document with this name into same directory!
        envelopeId = "",            // will retrieve this from second api call
        baseUrl = "";               // retrieved through the Login call

async.waterfall(
  [
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Step 1: Login (used to retrieve your accountId and baseUrl)
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function(next) {
        var url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
        var body = "";  // no request body for login api call

        // set request url, method, body, and headers
        var options = initializeRequest(url, "GET", body, email, password);

        // send the request...
        request(options, function(err, res, body) {
            if(!parseResponseBody(err, res, body)) {
                return;
            }
            baseUrl = JSON.parse(body).loginAccounts[0].baseUrl;
            next(null); // call next function
        });
    },

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Step 2: Create Envelope with Embedded Recipient (need to set |clientUserId| property)
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function(next) {    
        var url = baseUrl + "/envelopes";
        // following request body will place 1 signature tab 100 pixels to the right and
        // 100 pixels down from the top left of the document that you send in the request
        var body = {
            "recipients": {
                "signers": [{
                    "email": recipientEmail,
                    "name": recipientName,
                    "recipientId": 1,
                    "clientUserId": "1001",     //Required for embedded recipient
                    "tabs": {
                        "signHereTabs": [{
                            "xPosition": "100",
                            "yPosition": "100",
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "pageNumber": "1"                                                                                   
                        }]
                    }
                }]
            },
            "emailSubject": 'DocuSign API - Signature Request on Document Call',
            "documents": [{
                "name": documentName,
                "documentId": 1,
            }],
            "status": "sent"
        };

        // set request url, method, body, and headers
        var options = initializeRequest(url, "POST", body, email, password);

        // change default Content-Type header from "application/json" to "multipart/form-data"
        options.headers["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data";

        // configure a multipart http request with JSON body and document bytes
        options.multipart = [{
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Content-Disposition": "form-data",
                    "body": JSON.stringify(body),
                }, {
                    "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
                    'Content-Disposition': 'file; filename="' + documentName + '"; documentId=1',
                    "body": fs.readFileSync(documentName),
                }
        ];

        // send the request...
        request(options, function(err, res, body) {
            if(!parseResponseBody(err, res, body)) {
                return;
            }
            envelopeId = JSON.parse(body).envelopeId;
            next(null); // call next function
        });
    }, // end function    

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Step 3: Generate the Embedded Signing URL
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function(next) {
        var url = baseUrl + "/envelopes/" + envelopeId + "/views/recipient";
        var method = "POST";
        var body = JSON.stringify({
                "returnUrl": "http://www.docusign.com/devcenter",
                "authenticationMethod": "email",                    
                "email": email,                 
                "userName": recipientName,      
                "clientUserId": "1001", // must match clientUserId in step 2!
            });  

        // set request url, method, body, and headers
        var options = initializeRequest(url, "POST", body, email, password);

        // send the request...
        request(options, function(err, res, body) {
            if(!parseResponseBody(err, res, body))
                return;
            else
                console.log("\nNavigate to the above URL to start the Embedded Signing workflow...");
        });
    }
]);

//***********************************************************************************************
// --- HELPER FUNCTIONS ---
//***********************************************************************************************
function initializeRequest(url, method, body, email, password) {    
    var options = {
        "method": method,
        "uri": url,
        "body": body,
        "headers": {}
    };
    addRequestHeaders(options, email, password);
    return options;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function addRequestHeaders(options, email, password) {  
    // JSON formatted authentication header (XML format allowed as well)
    dsAuthHeader = JSON.stringify({
        "Username": email,
        "Password": password, 
        "IntegratorKey": integratorKey  // global
    });
    // DocuSign authorization header
    options.headers["X-DocuSign-Authentication"] = dsAuthHeader;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function parseResponseBody(err, res, body) {
    console.log("\r\nAPI Call Result: \r\n", JSON.parse(body));
    if( res.statusCode != 200 && res.statusCode != 201) { // success statuses
        console.log("Error calling webservice, status is: ", res.statusCode);
        console.log("\r\n", err);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now cant any one get my Docusign account credentials in front end?

Is this the correct approach I am using?

## Docusign

Answer (score 1):

The example you are citing is for Node.js environment where the JavaScript is on the server side.  If you keep it on the server side it is secure. If you post this code on the front end it will not be secure.  At the very least you will expose your Integrator Key which enables your solution to access DocuSign API.